Display a checkbox only for specific Product in WooCommerce Cart Page
I'm new to WooCommerce development and I am trying to figure out how to display a checkbox alongside some text only if a specific product is added to the cart.
Here is the code that I have that always display that text:
// Woocommerce - CHECKBOX Disclaimer on Add To Cart Page
add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'Disclaimer1_test', 10);

function Disclaimer1_test() {

        global $product;
            // How can I check against specific product ID?
            echo '<input type="checkbox" required />';
            echo '<p>This is a test</p>';
 
}

So, how can I display that checkbox only when a specific Product is in Cart?

You need to check in cart items product IDs if any defined product is in cart, to display the checkbox disclaimer (defining in the code the targeted product ID):
// Display a disclaimer checkbox on Cart Page, if specific product is in cart
add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'cart_disclaimer1_test', 10);
function cart_disclaimer1_test() {
    // Here, define the targeted product ID
    $targeted_product_id = 121;

    // Check if the targeted product is in cart
    if ( in_array( $targeted_product_id, array_column( WC()->cart->get_cart(), 'product_id' ) ) ) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="disclaimer1" required />';
        echo '<p>This is a test</p>';
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Addition
The same thing for multiple defined products:
// Display a disclaimer checkbox on Cart Page, if any of the defined products is in cart
add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'cart_disclaimer1_test', 10);
function cart_disclaimer1_test() {
    // Here, define the targeted product IDs
    $targeted_product_ids = array(121, 136);

    // Check if any of the targeted products is in cart
    if ( array_intersect( $targeted_product_ids, array_column( WC()->cart->get_cart(), 'product_id' ) ) ) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="disclaimer1" required />';
        echo '<p>This is a test</p>';
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
